# Strange behavior of QtCreator: no syntax highlight

Tags: qt-creator

- Platform: Qt 4.8.2, QtCreator 2.6.1, Win 7
- Problems: My QtCreator sometimes failed to recognize changes of the header file.

**Segment of MyProject.pro**

```
 SOURCES += somefiles.cpp \
            widget/problematic.cpp \
            someotherfiles.cpp

 HEADERS += somefiles.h \
            widget/problematic.h \
            someotherfiles.h
```

**Scenario**

My QtCreator was built from source using self-built Qt4.8.2 package (Both built using the same MinGW 64bit toolchain), and it once worked smoothly. Now for my project 'MyProject.pro', the IDE fails to track the changes I made to header file:  `widget/problematic.h`.

Case 1: When I add new class variables/functions to the header file, the IDE cannot recognize the newly added members at source file: new variables are not highlighted automatically, new function signatures cannot be popup when attempting to first defining them.

Case 2: When I change the variable from pointer-type to value-type at header file, the IDE keep saying the variable is a pointer, popping '->' operator instead of '.' operator for member selection.

During the same session (without closing the QtCreator), the issue remains even if I closed the files and reopen them. Only the problematic (.h, .cpp) experienced the issues.

So, what to check with the files/IDE?

---

#### Solved

It seems that after I properly rename the files to all lower cases, the problem vanished.

Comment: I experienced it with a qtcreator built using 4.7.3 too. But reopening the files solved those issues...